# Installing GoogleData API to work with Sheets

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

So I'm trying to install:
https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client

Into an XCode project of mine. It'll give me an error that says that it can't find a file from a project suffixed with GTM. So I copy GTM's source files into the project as well. Then it asks for another project's source files. Then I get those into the project. I've got to ask though..

*Is there a simple way to install the github project in the link above?*

Also, I'm trying to use Sheets with this. So I'm hoping that this project has some CRUD methods to deal with sheets? So in psuedocode below, this is what I'm hoping for.

```
GSheet *sheet = [GSheet sheetWithURL:@"http://www.google.com/drive/sheet/idnumber123252303"];
[sheet appendWithString:@"10,%t10,%t10"];
[sheet save];
```

So it fetches the sheet.
Adds a line to it.
Then saves the remote sheet.

*Is this the right API for the above task?*

Answer (score 1):

The Spreadsheets API is quite limited, and you are going to have a harder time to update the contents of the file. Try using App-script instead, as it already contains access to your sheets. You can use Appscript Execution API for ios: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/quickstart/ios.

Here is a sample project for accesing Google Drive: https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/tree/master/Examples/DriveSample

Comment: I like you're answer, it helps accomplish the situation I have. I don't know if I can make it the best answer though because it doesn't directly tell me how to do it with the Sheets API. Thanks though!